# Hibernate Restriction criteria to match from a collection property

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have a entity with a @ElementCollection field using hibernate eg:

```
@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@Column(name="years")
private Set<Integer> years = new HashSet<>();
```

where years is a set of years, I want to only filter those records which contain the particular queryYear in that set of years.

What kind of Restriction criteria can I use in Hibernate as Restriction.in doesn't work vice versa

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this in one criteria, since this cannot be done also in one normal query without using some syntax like `HAVING`, or using multiple join or other tricky workaround.

The closest criteria is using Restrictions.in then using agregate to count the row number, something like this:

```
c.add(Restrictions.in("years", years));
c.setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
    .add(Projections.groupProperty("id"))
    .add(Projections.count("id")));
```

All the result that have count = years.size is the id that you want.